# Accessing same database from different desktop applications

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, desktop-application, .net

I want to ask your opinion.

for example:
Restaurant A is a new restaurant in location B. Usually i manage the information just by book and maybe some excel formula to calculate. The information that i manage is about staff schedule, staff payroll, staff attendance, income, and storehouse. 
After a two years, i want to expand my business. I build the same restaurant, but in location C. and now, i realize. Using a book and excel is helpless. Just wasting time for me. i got an idea, how about if all the information store in the computer? Then, I planning to build a system that can help me  to manage the information. Actually is a desktop app. Then i bought two computer. one is for restaurant A in B. the other one is for restaurant A in C. i plan to install the desktop app in both of the computer and also install the desktop app in my personal laptop so that i can manage the restaurant eventhough i'm at home.

my question is :
1. which kind of database should i use? because i need to retrieve the data quickly.
2. where should i store the database? in both of computer for each restaurant? if yes, how can i access the data if i'm at home?

can you give me your opinion?

Comment: If you want all the information to be accessible from anywhere and everywhere, you need a centralised point for the data.  You would perhaps benefit from looking at hosted web application.

Comment: nope.. not a homework. my girlfriend ask me to make a system for her restaurant. but i confuse about the database.

@Dems a hosted application? okay. i got your point. but how if sometimes i lost the internet connection? how can i store the data? and if I using a data warehouse concept, thats mean whenever i using my laptop, I can get the information for both restaurant. Thats mean i need a centralised point also?

Comment: Buy something off the shelf unless there are very specific needs that you have that can't be met by a commercial product or service. Look for something web-based so you can access the data from anywhere.

Comment: So, you want all sites to be able to access all the information at all times with and without an internet connection.  You're aiming for far too much to do this yourself.

Comment: @TimLentine actually is a very specific needs. thats why my girlfriend asked me to build a system.

Comment: @Dems yeah. something like that. perhaps i dont have any deadline for this. so i will build it step by step with alot of calculation. what is your solution?

Comment: I would check out OpenERP before you write any code. They have a POS module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web application is more likely to solve your problem but if you still want to have a desktop application you can buy an hosting for a database and connect to it. IF this will be costly and you wont have internet access just use an accessdb with your application.Put the application and the database file in a usb drive and put it to any computer you want. The exe files may stay the same but you should move the database file to get the updated data in different locations.

Comment: hey, thanks for your opinion Ozgur Dogus.

Comment: not at all. If you can specify your needs more we can help better maybe. You can tell will it be an online application or not or how much data will it use in the database etc.

Comment: The database you use is a dimension of the speed of your application.Access is file based  maybe a bit slow with too big data but 100 records a day is not so big.I recommend you to use an access file.Compile your code and create the exe. put the database file in the same location with your exe and it will work anyhwere.but you should carry your db with you as i said

Comment: mmm. i got your point. how about if i use cloud database? will it work? i mean, what do you think about cloud databae? i just found it. in here, http://xeround.com/

Comment: its an option as well but i dont think there is a free version and you will always have to be connected to the internet if you use a cloud db in order your application to work properly.

Comment: okay.. i got it.. thanks for your opinion Ozgur. I'm really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem that will have an out-of-the-box solution.  Have you taken a look at an existing cloud solution?  I did a quick search and something like [this](http://www.timeforge.com) looks like it could work for what you need.

If you must create your own solution (which will probably be a lot more expensive) then I would definitely make use of a cloud database like SQL Azure.  That way it will be accessible from anywhere with no synching/merging required.

Comment: thanks for you opinion Kevin. but how about this? it is a cloud database. http://xeround.com/.. They say it's aa free. :D

Comment: I have never used that before but it looks like it could work.  Create a proof-of-concept app and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. there are different solutions to your problem.

1. If you have ur own network connection between your restaurants, then you can have a SQL Server installed at one Server(centralized) , and you can connect to it through windows app.
2. Developing a Web app which can be accessed through browser. U can  have all kinda info you need in click. That should be hosted in a server.

Comment: thanks for your opinion, Rajesh. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should go for Shared Web hosting that will give you database and web application hosting service.

e.g. Something that give Sql Express or Server with .Net web application host on IIS etc

Reason I am advising you to go for web application because it will be available 24/7 via the internet for you to access and update you data from anywhere and will give you more time to focus on managing restaurants rather than maintaining software.

Another advantage is you don't need to worry about installation of software and apps on every computer because you will be able to use your web application via a web browser

Comment: okay. thanks for you opinion, HatSoft